# cron fails when I type "crontab -e"

Tags: cron

```
/bin/sh: 1: subl: not found
crontab: "subl" exited with status 127
```

The last sysadmin must have had sublime installed. I would just like it to open in a shell (sh, bash, zsh) without the error.

What do I need to edit to make this a permanent change?

Thanks

Comment: `crontab` tends to use the `EDITOR` environment variable to know what editor to use.  Thus as a test/workaround, you might try _e.g._ `EDITOR=vi crontab -e`, to see if that works.  If so, making the change permanent would involve finding where those environment variables are set, system-wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, subl is likely sublime.

**To change it**

On some systems you can run (Ubuntu for sure):

```
# sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

There's also the select-editor command that is user specific:

```
$ select-editor
```

And you can set environment variables than override these settings in your .bashrc or system wide in /etc/profile, /etc/profile.d/something.sh, etc...:

```
export VISUAL=vim
export EDITOR="$VISUAL"
```

Comment: Another working option is to something like: sudo ln -s /bin/nano /usr/bin/subl